# I need to reload the Rest API deployed using Render/Cyclic everytime I need to see my project working

Tags: deployment, render, mern, cyclic

I have completed my project which fetches data using JSON server , which works perfect on local server. I deployed the REST API using Render. Now when I open my app I  see the data that should have been fetched but when I open the app link after 2 or three days that data was not fetched properly. But when I go to json server link and reload it the app starts working.

Same is the error for the MERN blog app that I created using MERN stack and deployed it on cyclic. Here I have to reload my app atleast 2 times before all the required data is fetched.

Now I don't understand what the problem is. But please help in understanding if it is something related to the code base or deployment server. If so then how should I correct it.

The error is something like this:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()